# how can i touch two objects by moving my finger?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I can't touch some objects in unity 5 by moving my finger .
I'm using `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name` to check which object is selected.but when i move my finger i have access to first object only. after finishing touching first object,second object will not understand my touch.i should remove my finger and touch second object again.

Comment: It is a normal behavior:`currentSelectedGameObject`holds the same gameobject until the end of the current touch.
If you want to select multiple gameObjects in the same swip you will to handle a list of game object.

`SetSelectedGameObject`could do the work but I am not still sure how to help you with your code. Could you past it ?

Comment: void FixedUpdate(){if (Input.touchCount > 0 && (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase != TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
              some job here 




            switch (EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name)
            { some jobs here}

Comment: Are your objects some UI elements or regular game assets? If they are UI maybe you can use the [Selectable class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here you test your Touch hits very often.
I suggest you another approach. 
Instead you could let your objects tell you when they are selected.
- a OnMouse event handler on each objects that trigger an event
- a class which listens to this event and store the gameobject sent by the event in a collection

En exemple of implementation :

The script for your objects :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class HoverDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void SelectEvent(GameObject go);
    public SelectEvent IsSelected;

    public delegate void DestroyEvent(GameObject go);
    public DestroyEvent Destroying;

    void OnMouseEnter ()
    {
        var es = EventSystem.current;
        if(es.currentSelectedGameObject != gameObject)
        {
            es.SetSelectedGameObject(gameObject);
            OnSelect();
        }
    }

    void OnSelect()
    {   
        Debug.Log("OnHover");
        IsSelected(gameObject);
    }

    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        Destroying(gameObject);
    }
}
```

The script which handle your object and store your selection into a collection

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class SelectedCollection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] AllMyObjects; //The array of all your selectable objects. Up to you to populate it.
    public List<GameObject> Collection{
        get {return _collection;}
    }

    private List<GameObject> _collection = new List<GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {
        AllMyObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SelectableObject"); // Just an exemple to populate your base array

        foreach(GameObject go in AllMyObjects)
        {
            go.GetComponent<HoverDetection>().IsSelected += store; //Fired by SetSelectedGameObject(GameObject) see : http://docs.unity3d.com/500/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject.html
            go.GetComponent<HoverDetection>().Destroying += clean; //Always unlink your delegats when an object is destroyed. Otherwise you risk some memory leaks. 
        }
    }

    private void store(GameObject go)
    {
        _collection.Add(go);
        Debug.Log(_collection.Count);
    }

    private void clean(GameObject go)
    {
        go.GetComponent<HoverDetection>().IsSelected -= store;
        go.GetComponent<HoverDetection>().IsSelected -= clean;
    }
}
```

All you need to do is replace OnMouseEnter by a proper code based on Touch events.